# Jquery hash set function

Tags: jquery, hash, tabs, hashchange

I need to call a function whenever this line is executed

```
window.location.hash = "#globalSearchView";
```

Currently I'm using hash change function

```
$(window).on("hashchange",function(e) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    switchtabs(hash);
});
```

It works only in case when hash is changed but doesn't work when same hash. I want to call a function **switchtabs** whenever this line

```
window.location.hash = "#whatever";
```

is executed no matter same hash or different. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
var l = location.prototype;
Object.defineProperty(l, 'hash', {
  get: function() { return this.hash; },
  set: function(t) { this.hash = t; switchtabs(t); }
});
```

Comment: No it doesn't work...it simply adds whole syntax of function in browser hash